# SQL Server Regex Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains Phone# like this:

```
Phone#
------------------
1234567890
2548796584
9999
2126543133
9999999999
999999
999
9853
9999999
```

Now I want a query that will return rows having only number 9 in it, in this case result should be.

```
Phone#
------------------
9999
9999999999
999999
999
9999999
```

I have heard about regex in Oracle but not in Sql Server. I'm using SQL server 2008 R2, can anyone help me please, thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need the power of regex for this, you can just use `Phone# like '%9%'` converting to a character type if necessary.

Comment: That won't do what they want @Laurence. The OP stated they want to return rows where the ONLY value is 9.

Comment: @SeanLange Quite right, missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a much simpler way than using CLR for this. The reason this like pattern works is we are finding rows that not like NOT 9. The carrot ( ^ ) in RegEx means NOT.

```
create table #Phones
(
    Num varchar(20)
)

insert #Phones
select '1234567890' union all
select '2548796584' union all
select '9999' union all
select '2126543133' union all
select '9999999999' union all
select '999999' union all
select '999' union all
select '9853' union all
select '9999999' union all
select '12345'

select *
from #Phones
where Num not like '%[^9]%'
```

Comment: Add an explanation to what the LIKE pattern means and you win!

Comment: Consider the following `WHERE num NOT LIKE '%9%'`. This would return all rows that **do not** contain a *9*. Similarly, `WHERE num NOT LIKE '%[0-9%]'` would return all rows that do not contain any digits. The square parentheses allow us to use range values. Now here comes the fun part: the carat `^`! This allows us to search for things that are *not* in the ranges, thus giving us `WHERE num NOT LIKE '%[^9]%'`. This will return all rows that "do not contain anything except a nine" i.e. rows that "contain nothing but 9's!"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
select * from Phones
where 1 = dbo.RegExpLike(number, '^9+$')
```

You can check more examples about using regex here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has limited regex functionality, but you can [add it using common language runtime procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx). You can get what you're looking for with the code below.

```
declare @table table (
  [phone] [sysname]);
insert into @table
        ([phone])
values      (N'1234567890'),
        (N'2548796584'),
        (N'9999'),
        (N'2126543133'),
        (N'9999999999'),
        (N'999999'),
        (N'999'),
        (N'9853'),
        (N'9999999');
select [phone] from   @table
where  patindex('%[0-8]%', [phone]) = 0;
```

Comment: It has some pretty rudimentary regex capabilities. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query.

```
SELECT  * FROM Phones
WHERE Number NOT LIKE '%[^9]%'
```

Comment: Kiran - phone numbers can often include non-numeric characters e.g. `+`, `()`, `-` to name but a few.